# Pathfinding through graph with special vertices

Tags: path-finding

Heyo!

So I've got this directed and/or undirected graph with a bunch of vertices and edges. In this graph there is a start vertex and an end vertex. There's also a subset of vertices which are coloured red (this subset can include the start and end vertices). Also, no pair of vertices can have more than one edge between them.

What I have to do is to find:

A) The shortest path that passes no red vertices

B) If there is a path that passes at least one red vertex

C) The path with the greatest amount of red vertices

D) The path with the fewest amount of red vertices

For A I use a breadth first search ignoring red branches. For B I simply brute force it with a depth first search of the graph. And for C and D I use dynamic programming, memoizing the number of red vertices I find in all paths, using the same DFS as in B.

I am moderately happy with all the solutions and I would very much appreciate any suggestions! Thanks!!

Comment: Does any of those path need to be optimal with respect to some length metric (beside having the required amount of red vertices), or does existence / construction of *a* path matching the red vertices criteria suffice?

Comment: The only one that has any criteria beyond the red vertices is A as it has to be the shortest path with no red vertices. Otherwise you're just looking for red vertices.

Comment: I'm starting to think that C is an NP-hard problem, and that I should use Dijkstra on D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For A I use a breadth first search ignoring red branches

A) is a Typical pathfinding problem happening in the sub-graph that contains no red edges. So your solution is good (could be improved with heuristics if you can come up with one, then use A*)

---

> For B I simply brute force it with a depth first search of the graph

Well here's the thing. Every optimal path `A->C` can be split at an arbitrary intermediate point `B`. A Nice property of optimal paths, is that every sub-path is optimal. So `A->B` and `B->C` are optimal.

This means if you *know* you must travel from some `start` to some `end` *through* an intermediary red vertex, you can do the following:

- Perform a BFS from the start vertex
- Perform a BFS from the endvertex backwards (If your edges are directed - as I think - you'll have to take them in reverse, here)

Alternate expanding both BFS so that  both their 'edge' (or open lists, as they are called) have the same distance to their respective start.

Stop when:

- One BFS hits a red vertex encountered by (or in the 'closed' list of) the other one. In this case, Each BFS can construct the optimal path to that commen vertex. Stitch both semi-paths, and you have your optimal path with at least a red vertex.
- One BFS is stuck ('open' list is empty). In this case, there is no solution.

---

> C) The path with the greatest amount of red vertices

This is a combinatorial problem. the first thing I would do is make a matrix of reachability of [start node + red nodes + end nodes] where:

```
reachability[i, j] = 1 iff there is a path from node i to node j
```

To compute this matrix, simply perform one BFS search starting at the start node and at every red  node. If the BFS reaches a red node, put a 1 in the corresponding line/column.

This will abstract away the underlying complexity of the graph, and make an order of magnitude speedup on the combinatorial search.

The problem is now a [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) through that connectivity matrix. dynamic programming would be the way to go indeed.

---

> D) The path with the fewest amount of red vertices

Simply perform a Dijkstra search, but use the following metric when sorting the nodes in the 'open' list:

```
dist(start, a) < dist(start, b) if:
    numRedNodesInPath(start -> a) < numRedNodesInPath(start -> b)
    OR (
      numRedNodesInPath(start -> a) == numRedNodesInPath(start -> b)
      AND
      numNodesInPath(start -> a) < numNodesInPath(start -> a)
    )
```

For this, when discovering new vertices, you'll have to store the path leading up to them (well, just the nb of nodes in the path, as well as the nb of red nodes, separately) in a dedicated map to be fetched. I mention this because usually, the length of the path is stored implicitly as  the position of the verrtex in the array. You'll have to enforce it explicitely in your case.

---

*Note on length optimality:*

Even though you stated you did not care about length optimality outside of problem A), the algorithm I provided will produce shortest-length solutions. In many cases (like in D) it helps Dijkstra converge better I believe.